# Find the value of $p$ such that $\cos(P \sin x)=\sin(P\cos x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Find the smallest positive value of $P$ for which the equation
>   $$\cos(P \sin x)=\sin(P\cos x)$$
>   is true, where $x\in[0^{\circ},360^{\circ}]$.

Comment: I take it this meant to be for a specified value of x, no?  So P is a function of x, not a constant.  What have you tried (some particular values of x work out easily and examples are always informative).

Comment: If $x=0$, we have $\cos(P\sin0)=\sin(P\cos0)$, or $1=\sin P$. But at $x=\pi/2$ we have $\cos P=0$. So, $P=\pi/2$. But what do you mean by "equation is true" exaclty?

Comment: @MichaelGaluza, I guess find a value of $P$ that makes the above an identity?

Comment: @ZainPatel, there is no such $P$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\cos (P \sin x) \equiv \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - P \sin x\right)$$

So your problem reduces to

$$\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - P \sin x\right) = \sin (P \cos x)$$

What can you conclude from this? Perhaps take the inverse sine of both sides?